# Rendering issue in java swing

Tags: java, swing, ubuntu-16.04

I have a java application with a GUI running in ubuntu 16.04 using jre 1.7 and I got some rendering issues. The following code is not the application code but a simple test case.

```
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Test {


  public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame f = new JFrame();
    f.setSize(400,200);

    String[] s = {"test", "of", "rendering"};
    JComboBox<String> cs = new JComboBox<>(s);
    f.add(cs);
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.pack();
    f.setVisible(true);

  }
}
```

The following images show the problem: I have 3 elements in the JcomboBox, however when I browse (either by the mouse or the keyboard) the display of the elements changes (which should not happen). The problem happens also in Jtree elements.
[image]

Any thoughts on this one.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1. Is the picture you're showing the output of the simple case you listed above? (Because I wonder if, despite your simple example, there's something else happening in your original code that isn't captured in the example). 2. Does this only happen when the JFrame is very small?

Comment: 1) A Java Swing/AWT GUI should be started on the EDT. 2) `f.pack();` should be kept, but it makes the earlier `f.setSize(400,200);` irrelevant.

Comment: Which Look and Feel is this with?

Comment: @david koelle the image is the output of the provided snap code

Comment: I just tested this on Windows 10, Java version `1.8.0_73` and was unable to reproduce this. This seems specific to either the Look and Feel or something internal to Linux distributions of Java. Do you have another Java version to test this with? Do you have another Look and Feel available?

Comment: @Obicere I dont use a specific Look and Feel and to reproduce the error you have de do several click. Didn't try it on windows yet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem as you, and I managed to get rid of this rather irritating bug by using the **Oracle Java JDK 7** instead of **OpenJDK 7** which seems to be having the above issue.

For me the issue is notable just by hovering over the different selections in a `JComboBox`. I did not have this problem using Windows so I figured switching versions of the Java JDK could give a different result.

The error is probably located somewhere inside the Swing repaint functions in OpenJDK as the repaint seems to be executed in the wrong thread. 
  By extending the `RepaintManager` class overriding the `addDirtyRegion(JComponent c, int x, int y, int w, int h)` with an added print out of `java.awt.EventQueue.isDispatchThread()` I could check the thread used during the repaint.

The above function returned *false* multiple times when hovering inside the `JComboBox` using OpenJDK but *true* when using the Oracle JDK. I hope someone smarter than me can pinpoint the error exactly and report it, as I have not had the time figure it out or to do a source comparison between the JDK implementations.

P.S. there seems to be an issue installing Oracle JDK 7 at the moment on Ubuntu using APT, so I downloaded the RPM package, converted it to a deb package using alien by using this method - [Oracle Java JDK 7 on Ubuntu Linux - Source or RPM Installation](https://linuxconfig.org/oracle-java-jdk-7-on-ubuntu-linux-source-or-rpm-installation)